# R function edit() often crashes unprovoced

Tags: r, crash, edit

I often experience sudden crashes of R, resulting in a new session, when using edit() to view a matrix or data frame. I fail to recognize any systemacy: Sometimes it crashes while opening the seperate edit window, another time during looking at or closing it. The size of the object to be viewed doesn't seem to matter either. Is there a known inherent instability of this function? If yes, is it associated with certain package incompatabilities? And third: Is there an alternative (besides View()) to edit()?

Comment: Hard to do anything with this.  Operating system, R version ... ??

Comment: I never use edit(). Just use `[<-`

Comment: In addition to the items asked by Ben, you should also say what this returns: `getOption("editor")`. Re: other options, Have you looked at the `?edit` page?

Comment: And: Are you aware of this"  Should you want the changes to apply to the object name you must assign the result of edit to name. "?

Comment: @ DWin: How to use [<- ? I failed googling it and I´m not sure how to evoke the R intern help page for the command. I am aware of the need to assign an edited file, but I merely use edit() to look at data, not to change it. I also looked at ?edit, but couldn´t find any hints regarding known crashing issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an up-to-date Windows 7 and the base R-3.0.2. Here is getOption("editor"):

function(name, file, title) {

```
  # use internal editor for files and functions, otherwise 
  # delegate to the default editor
  if (is.null(name) || is.function(name)) {

     # if no name then use file
     if (is.null(name)) {
        if (!is.null(file) && nzchar(file)) 
           targetFile <- file
        else
           targetFile <- scratchFile
     }
     # otherwise it's a function, write it to a file for editing
     else {
        functionSrc <- .rs.deparseFunction(name, TRUE)
        targetFile <- scratchFile
        writeLines(functionSrc, targetFile)
     }

     # invoke the RStudio editor on the file
     if (.Call("rs_editFile", targetFile)) {

        # try to parse it back in
        newFunc <- try(eval.parent(parse(targetFile)),
                       silent = TRUE)
        if (inherits(newFunc, "try-error")) {
           stop(newFunc, "You can attempt to correct the error using ",
                title, " = edit()")
        }

        return(newFunc)
     } 
     else {
        stop("Error occurred while editing function '", name, "'")
     }
  }
  else
     edit(name, file, title, editor=defaultEditor)
```

}